# Android nested dialog with datetimepicker

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker

I am trying to display a dialog with a image button, onClick of image second dialog should be open with datatime picker and user will select the date which should be reflected in first dialog. But the problem is onClick of image , it doesn't open second dialog with datetimepicker.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button_city).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            // addCity(view);


             LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ViewTripActivity.this);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.city_prompt, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewTripActivity.this);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            ib1 = (ImageButton)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            ib2 = (ImageButton)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            final EditText  et3=(EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etarrivaldate);
             final EditText et4=(EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.etdeparturedate);
             et3.setEnabled(false);
             et3.setFocusable(false);
             et4.setEnabled(false);
             et4.setFocusable(false);

             ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                           showDialog(1);

             }

            // @Override
             @Deprecated
             protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

              return new DatePickerDialog(ViewTripActivity.this, datePickerListener1, year, month, day);

             }

             private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
              public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                  Log.d("In ADD CITY","DAY"+selectedDay);
                  Log.d("In ADD CITY","month"+selectedMonth);
                  Log.d("In ADD CITY","year"+selectedYear);
                  et3.setText(selectedDay+"/" + (selectedMonth + 1)+"/"+ selectedYear);
              }
             };



             });



             ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewTripActivity.this, "click of departuredate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  showDialog(2);

                 }

                 @Deprecated
                 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

                         return new DatePickerDialog(ViewTripActivity.this, datePickerListener2, year, month, day);

                 }


                 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {


                          Log.d("In ADD CITY","DAY"+selectedDay);
                          Log.d("In ADD CITY","month"+selectedMonth);
                          Log.d("In ADD CITY","year"+selectedYear);
                          et4.setText(selectedDay+"/" + (selectedMonth + 1)+"/"+ selectedYear);
                      }
                     };


                 }); 





             //code to show alert window to add city
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        Toast.makeText(ViewTripActivity.this, "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                                                }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
         }
     });
```

Comment: post what you have tried till now

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I have a add button onclick opens a dialog where I add city details like name, arrivaldate and departuredate . In this dialog I have two images one to add arrivaldate and another for departuredate. Onclick of this image I want to show a dialog with datetime picker which is not happening